# Unirest JSONElement NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, rest, gson, unirest

I am using Unirest library to call publically available REST endpoint with following lines of code:

```
public void callRest() {
    String url = "https://upstream.com/token"
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = (HttpResponse<JsonNode>) Unirest.post(url).
            field("username", "###").
            field("password", "###").
            field("grant_type", "password").
            field("client_id", "####").
            field("client_secret", "####").asJson().getBody();
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.Gson.newBuilder()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
    at kong.unirest.json.JSONElement.<clinit>(JSONElement.java:39)
    at kong.unirest.JsonNode.<init>(JsonNode.java:44)
    at kong.unirest.JsonResponse.toJsonNode(JsonResponse.java:49)
    at kong.unirest.JsonResponse.getNode(JsonResponse.java:43)
    at kong.unirest.JsonResponse.<init>(JsonResponse.java:35)
    at kong.unirest.apache.BaseApacheClient.transformBody(BaseApacheClient.java:53)
    at kong.unirest.apache.ApacheClient.request(ApacheClient.java:127)
    at kong.unirest.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:213)
```

The line that stands out is

```
at kong.unirest.json.JSONElement.<clinit>(JSONElement.java:39)
```

where the unirest library is just declaring

```
private static transient final Gson PRETTY_GSON = new Gson().newBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

In JSONElement class. I have followed the exact guideline given on Unirest documentation which you can find [here](http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/#requestshttps://).

The POM dependencies I have added are as follows :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.00</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.00</version>
            <classifier>standalone</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was a version conflict with Unirest. When I deleted

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.00</version>
            <classifier>standalone</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

and fetched result by just `.asJson()` then everything worked for me.